# Problem with Texture on Plane

Tags: texturing, image

I've got a little problem. I tried to put a texture on a plane, but now it looks like this.

[image: My problem.]

It looks very buggy and its cut at the half of the plane. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way to project an image onto a plane.

1. Enable the images as planes addon under 'user preferences'[image]
2. Press 'SHIFT + A' -> Mesh -> Images as planes
   [image]
3. Then search for your image and voila!

This does not really answer your question but it should work out fine for you I guess.

If you really need to fix the problem you're facing:

1. Get into 'edit mode'
2. Select all (press 'A')
3. Go to top view in ortographic projection
4. Press 'U'
5. select 'project from view'
6. Go to image editor en scale your UV's if necessary
7. Done!

If you still have problems after these steps, try recalculating the normals.
*(shortcut: 'CTR +N')*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go into edit mode with `tab`, then double press `a` to select all the vertices. Then press `u` and choose *Unwrap*. Then switch to the **UV Editor** panel and move the vertices around, scale them, etc until you get the image you'd like. I do not currently have access to a computer, but when I do I'll provide screenshots to explain what I mean if needed.